# Create multiple view tables from a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that creates a view table and it goes as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_table AS
SELECT ………………
       ………………
FROM shop_table 
     JOIN …………  ON ………… = ………… 
     JOIN …………  ON ………… = ………… 
WHERE shopid = 1 
GROUP BY e.employee_name 
ORDER BY COUNT(p.payment_amount) ASC LIMIT 1
```

There are 20 Shops in my database. The query above will create the view table containing data for just a single shop as you can see from the `WHERE shopid = 1`.

Now I would like to create a view table for every single (all of the 20) shop in my database when this query is run rather than just for one.

How can I do this? Will I have to create 20 different queries and change the value in the `WHERE` clause each time or is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you might write a function that accepts an argument and use that argument in the function to implement a WHERE clause so you get the shop you desire.

Comment: What are you joining this table with? Why don't you use UNION ALL?

Comment: This is a SQL Anti-Pattern.  Why do you want one View per entry in `shop_table`?  Why not a view that returns one employee per shop?  *(The top performer in each shop)*

Comment: @MatBailie Any ideas how I can do as you suggested for my query. I can remove the `WHERE` clause but that will return all employees. How can i get the employee with most sales from each shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this in MySQL, none of them pretty.  I believe MySQL 8 will have `ROW_NUMBER()` and `RANK()` to make it *much* cleaner and quicker, but for now here is how I would do something like this in views...

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xxcCnsJWgbXBxhRx39bUV9/0

```
create table shop (
  id int
);

create table employee (
  id int,
  shop_id int
);

create table sale (
  employee_id int,
  payment_amount int
);


insert into shop values (1);
insert into shop values (2);
insert into shop values (3);


insert into employee values (1, 1);
insert into employee values (2, 1);
insert into employee values (3, 1);

insert into employee values (4, 2);
insert into employee values (5, 2);
insert into employee values (6, 2);

insert into employee values (7, 3);
insert into employee values (8, 3);
insert into employee values (9, 3);


insert into sale values (1, 100);
insert into sale values (1, 200);

insert into sale values (2, 300);

insert into sale values (3, 50);
insert into sale values (3, 50);
insert into sale values (3, 50);


insert into sale values (4, 200);
insert into sale values (4, 300);

insert into sale values (5, 400);

insert into sale values (6, 150);
insert into sale values (6, 150);
insert into sale values (6, 150);

insert into sale values (7, 200);
insert into sale values (7, 100);

insert into sale values (8, 250);

insert into sale values (9, 100);
insert into sale values (9, 150);
insert into sale values (9, 150);


create view shop_employee_total_sale as
  select
    employee_id, shop_id, sum(payment_amount) total_payment
  from
    sale
  inner join
    employee
      on employee.id = sale.employee_id
  group by
    employee_id, shop_id
;

create view shop_top_employee as
  select
    shop_employee_total_sale.shop_id,
    shop_employee_total_sale.employee_id,
    shop_employee_total_sale.total_payment
  from
    shop_employee_total_sale
  inner join
  (
    select shop_id, max(total_payment) as total_payment from shop_employee_total_sale group by shop_id
  )
    shop_top_total
      on  shop_top_total.shop_id       = shop_employee_total_sale.shop_id
      and shop_top_total.total_payment = shop_employee_total_sale.total_payment
;

select * from shop_top_employee;

select * from shop_top_employee where shop_id = 1;

select * from shop_top_employee where shop_id = 2;

select * from shop_top_employee where shop_id = 3;
```

Note that I deliberately chose an example where one shop has two employees with the same total payments.  In that case they're both "top performer" and two records are returned for that shop.

***EDIT:*** By way of example, how it improves when you get access to `RANK()`...

```
CREATE VIEW better_shop_top_employee AS
  SELECT
    employee_id,
    shop_id,
    SUM(payment_amount) total_payment,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY shop_id ORDER BY SUM(payment_amount) DESC)  shop_rank
  FROM
    sale
  INNER JOIN
    employee
      ON employee.id = sale.employee_id
  GROUP BY
    employee_id,
    shop_id
;

SELECT * FROM better_shop_top_employee WHERE shop_id = 1 AND rank = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I created a new question which has the query I have and the problem. Please could you take a look at it and tailor the answer to that if you can. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533531/mysql-how-to-limit-one-result-per-id

Comment: You want me to do that for you, but you didn't even up-vote either answer to *this* question? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a stored procedure. Here is a link to a tutorial on using stored procedures in mysql

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx

If you want to use the result as a table itself in another query then a function is the way to go, but it is more limited in what it can achieve. (Your example is pretty trivial though)