# MySQL - How to limit one result per ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which creates a view table showing the highest salesperson in a store with few other details:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW sales_data AS 
SELECT s.storename AS "Store", 
       e.employee_name AS "Employee", 
       e1.employee_name AS "Manager", 
       SUM(p.total_sale_value) AS "Sales Value" 
FROM fss_Shop s 
       JOIN Employee e ON e.storeid = s.storeid 
       JOIN Payment p ON p.employee_number = e.employee_number 
       JOIN Employee e1 ON e1.employee_number = e.manager_number 
WHERE s.storeid=1 
GROUP BY e.employee_name 
ORDER BY SUM(p.total_sale_value) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The above query will only show the sales data for a single store and the reason being as I have stated `WHERE s.storeid=1`. I have 20 stores in my table. How can I change the above query so that it gives me sales data for 20 stores (so that's 20 rows).

Comment: If you remove the `WHERE s.storeid=1` can you make the group by `GROUP BY e.employee_name , s.storeid` and see if that works?

Comment: @dimwittedanimal That is much better. But it is still giving me multiple salespeople from the same store.

Comment: Remove where clause and update your `GROUP BY  s.storeid`

Comment: @HoldTight sorry I misunderstood what you were going for. Remove `e.employee_name` from the group by as in M Khalid Junaid's comment

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid I tried that earlier and that will group by storeid but the data returned will be incorrect, in terms of sales value and the top salesperson.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. You want to sum all the sale values for all employees, and grab the highest for each store. Correct?

Comment: @dimwittedanimal Yes that’s correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW employee_sales_totals AS
    SELECT
        e.*,
        SUM(p.total_sale_value)   AS total_sale_value
    FROM
        Employee e
    INNER JOIN
        Payment  p
            ON p.employee_number = e.employee_number 
    GROUP BY
        e.id  -- This should be the Primary Key / Surrogate Key of the employee table
;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW shop_top_employee_by_sales_value AS
    SELECT
        s.storename          AS "Store", 
        e.employee_name      AS "Employee", 
        m.employee_name      AS "Manager", 
        p.total_sale_value   AS "Sales Value" 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT storeid, MAX(total_sale_value) AS total_sale_value
          FROM employee_sales_totals
      GROUP BY storeid
    )
       p
    INNER JOIN
        employee_sales_totals   e
            ON  e.storeid          = p.storeid
            AND e.total_sale_value = p.total_sale_value
    INNER JOIN
        fss_Shop   s 
            ON s.storeid = e.storeid 
    INNER JOIN
        Employee   m
            ON m.employee_number = e.manager_number 
;
```

As per the answer to your previous question, if multiple employees are tied for the same total sales amount in the same store, all such employees would be returned.

Comment: Im getting a syntax error at line 4. `SUM(p.total_sales_value)   AS total_sales_value
    FROM
        Employee e
    INNER JOIN
   ' at line 4 `

Comment: @HoldTight - It's just a comma missing at the end of the line before.

Comment: Now its giving one at `line 2` for the second query

Comment: These are simple to debug. I'm sure you can work them out if you try ;)  Missing `AS` from preceding line.

Comment: Yes i just realised.

Comment: :)  If you do spot any other silly mistakes and work them out, please do let me know though, I'm just jesting...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160026/discussion-between-holdtight-and-matbailie).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a ranking variable by *SalesValue* for each employee per store and then choose the `RANK=1` in outer query:

```
SELECT main.Store, main.Employee, main.Manager, main.SalesValue
FROM
 (SELECT agg.*,      
         @store:=agg.Store AS CURR_STORE,
         @rank:=CASE WHEN @val > agg.SalesValue THEN @rank+1 ELSE 1 END AS RANK,
         @val:=CASE WHEN @store <> agg.Store THEN @val ELSE agg.SalesValue END AS CURR_VAL
  FROM
    (SELECT s.storename AS "Store", 
            e.employee_name AS "Employee", 
            e1.employee_name AS "Manager", 
            SUM(p.total_sale_value) AS "SalesValue"
     FROM fss_Shop s 
     INNER JOIN Employee e ON e.storeid = s.storeid 
     INNER JOIN Payment p ON p.employee_number = e.employee_number 
     INNER JOIN Employee e1 ON e1.employee_number = e.manager_number  
     GROUP BY s.storename, 
              e.employee_name, 
              e1.employee_name
    ) As agg
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank:= 0) AS r1
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @val:= 0) AS r2
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @store:= 0) AS r3
  ORDER BY agg.Store, agg.SalesValue DESC
 ) As main
WHERE main.RANK = 1;
```

**DEMO**

[Rextester](http://rextester.com/TGF70026) *(using random data with only one Sales table)*

---

Alternatively, if variables cannot be used, consider creating two views where latter references the former: 1) initial aggregate query, 2) correlated subquery to retrieve top employee per store

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW sales_data AS 
SELECT s.storename AS "Store", 
       e.employee_name AS "Employee", 
       e1.employee_name AS "Manager", 
       SUM(p.total_sale_value) AS "SalesValue"
FROM fss_Shop s 
INNER JOIN Employee e ON e.storeid = s.storeid 
INNER JOIN Payment p ON p.employee_number = e.employee_number 
INNER JOIN Employee e1 ON e1.employee_number = e.manager_number  
GROUP BY s.storename, 
         e.employee_name, 
         e1.employee_name;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW top_sales_data AS 
SELECT s.*
FROM sales_data s 
WHERE (SELECT Count(*) FROM sales_data sub
       WHERE sub.SalesValue > s.SalesValue 
       AND sub.Store = s.Store) = 0;
```

Comment: You can't use variable assignments in views.

Comment: Good catch! Indeed, one day soon MySQL will have [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) as version 8 is promising! I add alternative.

Comment: I think you should have `= 0`?  As in "where there are no rows with a higher sales value"?  That said `NOT EXISTS (<query with no need for a group by>)` may be slightly faster...

Comment: `>=` and `= 1` has a problem : If two employees are tied for first place, this will return no rows *(as opposed to two rows)*.

Comment: Correct again. Unless OP can interject here, *SalesValue* looks to be a precise numeric value of decimal digits that may not coincide across other. There is a way to adjust for ties in correlated subqueries if needed.

Comment: Well, it's probably dollars and cents, or euros and cents, etc.  So it may not be likely to happen in any one particular case, but over time that likelihood grows until it is more likely than not to happen at least once eventually.  As this can easily be fixed with `>` and `= 0`, I'm not sure I see the benefit in the current solution.  *(Ties are unlikely in a 100m sprint, but watch enough races and they happen...)*